# How to share non-pickable complex Object between two processes in Python

Tags: python, object, multiprocessing

In python I have a Singleton Class A Object ObjA that contains list of object of Class B and class C internally like follows.

```
ObjA.value = 10
ObjA.listB = [objB_1, objB_2, objB_3]
ObjA.listC = [ObjC_1, objC_2, objC_3]
```

I have a requirement to share this complex ObjA between Processes P1 and P2.

P1 can add/delete objects that are stored in the list within objA.
P2 want to read/update objects that are stored in these lists listA and listB

As I understand objA is considered as non-pickable object. My question is How to share objA between P1 and P2 so that they can read/write the objects that are stored listB and listC.

Thank you for your time.

Thanks
Tom

Comment: My recommendation that if you are manipulating the same data set across different processes you might want to consider using a proper database.

Comment: What exactly makes it non-pickleable?  When you are sharing information between processes, you are going to need to be able to *serialize* the shared information.  Could you write custom serialization / deserialization?

Comment: Given that object A contains list of objects, does't that make it non-pickable ? Is there any example I can refer to for custom serialization/deserialization

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing those lists in an object, you might want to create a `multiprocessing.Manager()` then create lists under that manager. For example, in the main process:

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
counter = manager.Value(int, 10)
listB = manager.list([objB_1, objB_2, objB_3])
listC = manager.list([objC_1, objC_2, objC_3])
```

Now, you can pass those values and lists (proxies to be exact) to the processes. In the the sub processes:

```
# Use or update the value
someVar = counter.value
counter.value += 1

# Manipulate the list proxy as it was a real list
del listB[1]
listB.append(newObject)
listB[0] = updatedObject
```